# Get the height of colored area in Javascript to restrict the popup to that area

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, wkwebview

To indicate a change I am [coloring the changed area in green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JR2Uf.png)-see pic.
When tapped on it Javascript returns the content in "Title" attribute which will be shown with a pop up using native iOS code.
Now I want to restrict the pop up only to the green area when scrolled. Is there a way javascript returns the dimensions of green color in pixels . Or is there a better alternative way to implement this

Attached the sample picture. 
Javascript code

```
function initialize(){
$("a[name*='changesColor']").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("onclick","");
    $(this).click(function(){

        sendCommand("tip_change",$(this).parent().attr('title'), height);
    });
});
}
```

Html code

```
    `<div title="Adds reference to the eFAOM regarding the delegation of authority to the Managing Director, Inflight Safety and Training to maintain and revise information as needed.">
     <a xmlns:atict="http://www.arbortext.com/namespace/atict" name="changesColor2" id="changesColor2">
        <div class="highlight" style="background-color:#D1FFD1;">
            <div class="para_space" id="d12957e3748">Delegates the authority to maintain and the FAOM/eFAOM to the Managing Director, Inflight Safety and Training.
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    </div>
```

`

iOS code

```
 if([command isEqualToString:@"tip_change"]){
    NSString *text = params!=nil?[params objectAtIndex:0]:nil;
    if (text==nil) {
        return;
    }
    [self showTips:text atPoint:lastTouchPoint];
    return;
   }
```